# How to use WHERE in VIEW?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, view

In myView in the database, I have:

```
 SELECT orderhdr3_.id AS col_0_0_,
    gnrlorg2_.id AS col_1_0_,
    gnrlorg2_.name AS col_2_0_,
    gnrlcustom1_.id AS col_3_0_,
    gnrlcustom1_.name AS col_4_0_,
    orderhdr3_.order_no AS col_5_0_,
    orderhdr3_.cust_ref_no AS col_6_0_,
    tripinfo4_.job_no AS col_7_0_,
    orderhdr3_.order_type AS col_8_0_,
    servicetyp5_.code AS col_9_0_,
    tripinfo4_.service_provider_id AS col_10_0_,
    tripinfo4_.service_personnel AS col_11_0_,
    orderhdr3_.status AS col_12_0_,
    orderhdr3_.completed_date AS col_13_0_,
    orderhdr3_.reason_code AS col_14_0_,
    orderhdr3_.remarks AS col_15_0_,
    orderhdr3_.source_order_hdr_location_id AS col_16_0_,
    orderhdrlo7_.unit_no AS col_17_0_,
    orderhdrlo7_.name AS col_18_0_,
    orderhdrlo7_.address AS col_19_0_,
    orderhdrlo7_.postal_code AS col_20_0_,
    orderhdrlo7_.zone AS col_21_0_,
    orderhdrlo7_.contact AS col_22_0_,
    orderhdrlo7_.phone AS col_23_0_,
    orderhdrlo7_.email AS col_24_0_,
    orderhdrlo7_.op_date AS col_25_0_,
    orderhdrlo7_.instruction AS col_26_0_,
    orderhdr3_.dest_order_hdr_location_id AS col_27_0_,
    orderhdrlo6_.unit_no AS col_28_0_,
    orderhdrlo6_.name AS col_29_0_,
    orderhdrlo6_.address AS col_30_0_,
    orderhdrlo6_.postal_code AS col_31_0_,
    orderhdrlo6_.zone AS col_32_0_,
    orderhdrlo6_.contact AS col_33_0_,
    orderhdrlo6_.phone AS col_34_0_,
    orderhdrlo6_.email AS col_35_0_,
    orderhdrlo6_.op_date AS col_36_0_,
    orderhdrlo6_.instruction AS col_37_0_,
    orderdet11_.product_code AS col_39_0_,
    orderdet11_.product_desc AS col_40_0_,
    orderdet11_.order_qty AS col_41_0_,
    orderdet11_.serviced_qty AS col_42_0_,
    orderdet11_.reason_code AS col_43_0_,
    orderhdr3_.active_ind AS col_44_0_,
    tripinfo4_.active_ind AS col_45_0_,
    gnrlorg2_.active_ind AS col_46_0_,
    gnrlcustom1_.active_ind AS col_47_0_,
    commusersc0_.comm_user_id AS col_48_0_,
    orderhdr3_.org_id AS col_49_0_,
    orderhdr3_.customer_id AS col_50_0_,
    orderhdrlo6_.op_date AS col_51_0_,
    orderhdrlo6_.op_date AS col_52_0_,
    orderhdr3_.id AS col_53_0_,
    orderdet11_.order_hdr_id AS col_54_0_,
    orderhdrlo6_.op_date AS col_55_0_,
    tripinfo4_.job_no AS col_56_0_,
    orderhdr3_.seq AS col_57_0_,
    orderhdr3_.order_no AS col_58_0_
   FROM comm_users_customers commusersc0_
     JOIN gnrl_customer gnrlcustom1_ ON commusersc0_.gnrl_customer_id = gnrlcustom1_.id
     JOIN gnrl_org gnrlorg2_ ON gnrlcustom1_.gnrl_org_id = gnrlorg2_.id
     CROSS JOIN order_det orderdet11_
     JOIN order_hdr orderhdr3_ ON gnrlcustom1_.id = orderhdr3_.customer_id
     JOIN trip_info tripinfo4_ ON orderhdr3_.trip_info_id = tripinfo4_.id
     JOIN service_type servicetyp5_ ON orderhdr3_.service_type_id = servicetyp5_.id
     JOIN order_hdr_location orderhdrlo6_ ON orderhdr3_.dest_order_hdr_location_id = orderhdrlo6_.id
     JOIN order_hdr_location orderhdrlo7_ ON orderhdr3_.source_order_hdr_location_id = orderhdrlo7_.id
     JOIN order_hdr_location_time_windows timewindow8_ ON timewindow8_.order_hdr_location_id = orderhdr3_.dest_order_hdr_location_id
     JOIN order_hdr_location orderhdrlo9_ ON timewindow8_.order_hdr_location_id = orderhdrlo9_.id;
```

In my code, I would like to filter using WHERE

```
SELECT * FROM myView view WHERE view.order_no = ?
```

but Java/PostgreSQL give error:

> ERROR: column view.order_no does not exist

Please help as this is quite complicated as it involves multiple tables and a lot of columns. I am not sure why view.order_no does not exist because it is selected in col_5_0

Comment: How should SQL know what tables are involved just by selecting from a view? If the **column of the view** is named `id`, then either just write `... WHERE id = ?` or `... WHERE myView.id = ?`.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM .. WHERE col_5_0_ = ?`

Comment: obviously there's no column name or alias as `order_no` within the query of the view.

Comment: I have tried WHERE col_5_0 = ? but not success. Please help. thanks

Comment: `order_no` was renamed to `col_5_0_`  (not `col_5_0`). But those aliases make no sense whatsoever. You should re-create your view with readable and understandable column aliases.

Answer (score 1):

You can reference the view by its name:

```
SELECT * FROM myView WHERE id = ?
```

Also `view` is a keyword in sql.

Comment: I have tried that. It says column view.id does not exist. Please help. thanks.

Comment: @Shazam can you paste the whole view definition in the question?

Comment: I have pasted the whole view. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: @Shazam try now

Comment: Still can't. I have tried WHERE myView.order_no but not working. Please help. thanks

Comment: @Shazam did that help?

Comment: @Shazam wrong aliases are probably your problem, but you already got noticed in the comment secion and Gordon Linoff's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have renamed the column `order_no` as `col_5_0_`.  So you need to use that:

```
SELECT *
FROM myView v
WHERE v.col_5_0_ = ?;
```

That is, you can only reference the columns that are returned by the view.

Renaming columns to meaningless strings seems like a really bad idea -- at least if the views are exposed to human beings.  It is not clear to me why anyone would want to obfuscate them.

Also, don't use `view` as a table alias (or any other identifier).  It is a SQL keyword, and it is best to avoid those as identifiers.

Answer (score 0):

Create your view like this way and use view reference in where clause

```
CREATE VIEW view_name 
AS
    SELECT column1, column2, ...
    FROM table_name
    WHERE condition;
```

You can also filter rows during view creation.

```
SELECT * 
FROM view_name 
WHERE view_name.col_name = ?
```